# Не могу разобраться с mysql_fetch_array в системе отображения онлайн пользователей

Tags: база-данных, php

Делаю на сайте систему отображения онлайнов и офлайнов на php + Mysql - принцип - при любой активности на сайте запускается скрипт который заносит в БД время последней активности для соответствующего id пользователя вот такой скрипт (он работает)

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i");
$resultonline = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET timeout='$date' WHERE id='$id'",$db);
```

Далее на странице пользователя действует скрипт сравнивающий его "текущее время - 1 минута" и если последняя активность зарегистрированная в БД была больше чем минуту назад то помечает его как офлайна если меньше то как онлайна!

```
$onstat = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND timeout < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())",$db);
$onlinestat = mysql_fetch_array($onstat);
if ($onlinestat['id'] == $id) {
    print "онлайн";
}else{
    print "Офлайн";
}
```

вот в нем где-то и ошибка! - `mysql_fetch_array` - выдает ошибку что ему не возвращается правильный боллеан - следовательно ошибка где-то в вычислении? Помогите разобраться! Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Да php проверка - я думаю заврепить дату за переменной и вычислять переменными хмм

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в написание функции DATEADD - правильно DATE_ADD, подробные [Mysql - DATE_ADD](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp)

Comment: к сожалению не помогло( все так же выдает: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\apache\localhost\www\page.php on line 43

Comment: `$onstat = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND timeout < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())",$db);` замените на это
`$onstat = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='$id' AND timeout < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())",$db) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Кстати там синтаксис другой у этой функции `timeout < DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())`  
 это записывается так  
 `DATE_ADD(timeout,INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)`

Comment: Спасибо большое! все заработало! Держите + )

Comment: сделал только вот так 

$onstat = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND timeout < DATE_ADD(timeout,INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) ",$db);
$onlinestat = mysql_fetch_array($onstat);
if ($onlinestat['id'] == $id) {
print <<<HERE
онлайн
HERE;
}else{
print <<<HERE
Офлайн
HERE;
}

Comment: Я рад, что у Вас получилось, обращайтесь ;-)

Comment: а маожно такой вопрос..
как правильней написать такое сравнение??

if ($myrow['timeout'] < DATE_ADD(timeout,INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)) {
$onint = 1;
}else{
$onint = 0;}

Comment: в sql-запросе Или php проверка?